# Cast a class that implements all of the methods in an interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, casting, polymorphism

If a class happens to implement all of the methods in an interface (but doesn't explicitly implement it), is there a way of casting an instance of the class to that interface?

To demonstrate the issue I've set up the following simple classes. `Scavenger` is a demonstration `class` that I want to unit test.

The `IFinder` `interface` can be implemented by a `dictionary` (or could be implemented some other way). Finder is a sample implementation of the interface using a dictionary to handle the lifting.

```
//System under test
public class Scavenger
{
    private readonly IFinder _lookup;

    public Scavenger(IFinder lookup)
    {
        _lookup = lookup;
    }

    public string WhatIs(string key)
    {
        if (_lookup.ContainsKey(key)) return _lookup[key];
        return null;
    }
}

//Interface that can be met by a dictionary
public interface IFinder
{
    bool ContainsKey(string key);
    string this[string key] { get; set; }
}


//Implement IFinder using a dictionary
public class Finder : Dictionary<string,string>, IFinder
{
    public Finder()
    {
        this.Add("A","Hello");
        this.Add("B","Goodbye");
    }
}
```

I'd hoped to be able to setup a test for Scavenger along these lines...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This will fail because due to failed cast a Dictionary to an IFinder
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void LookupUsingDictionary()
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dic.Add("A","B");
        var scavenger = new Scavenger(dic as IFinder);
        var res = scavenger.WhatIs("A");
        Assert.AreEqual("B", res);
    }
```

The issue is that `(dic as IFinder) == null`. I know I can setup a mock class similar to Finder, or use a mocking framework, but I just **want to check if I'm missing some way of casting a dictionary to do the job**.

Comment: What an excellent set of answers! For my purposes I think @MarcinJuraszek has told me what I need to know: That I'm not missing a way of casting. IMHO The dynamic workaround is too nasty for me in real life, an adaptor class would work but adds extra classes for testing, where I could just use a mock, the duck typing libraries are probably OTT, so it looks like it is back to Mocking :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. That's called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and C# does not allow that.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that `dynamic` is considered duck typing, which is supported by c#.

Comment: @JohnGibb No, it's not.  `dynamic` is dynamic typing, which is quite different.  See [Eric Lippert's explanation of the difference](http://ericlippert.com/2014/01/02/what-is-duck-typing/)

Comment: @JohnGibb Casting to `dynamic` does not allow you to pass your object to method which requires `IMyInterface` instance when the object hidden under `dynamic` does not implement it.

Comment: @Servy I've already read it. His conclusion is that duck typing is too loosely defined to be meaningful. `dynamic` is a form of duck typing, and structural typing is another. You might say `dynamic` walks like duck typing and it quacks like duck typing...

Comment: @JohnGibb No, `dynamic` just says that it'll accept everything, even if it doesn't walk or quack at all.  It provide no typing at all, really.

Comment: @Servy I disagree. Python is a canonical example of duck typing, and it works very similarly to `dynamic`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python

Comment: @JohnGibb I consider the canonical example to be templates in C++.  The template itself can write whatever it wants, and the caller's code will only compile if it meets the given contract.

Comment: Same Wikipedia page contains an entry for C#: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_C.23

Answer (score 3):

When you have an interface and a class that implements all of the appropriate methods, but doesn't implement the interface, you can use the adaptor pattern to accopmlish your goal.  Create a class that implements the given interface and accepts an instance of the type that has all of the needed methods.  It can then redirect all of the methods to the composed class:

```
public class DictionaryFinder : IFinder
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> dictionary;
    public DictionaryFinder(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }


    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get { return dictionary[key]; }
        set { dictionary[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
var scavenger = new Scavenger(new DictionaryFinder(dic));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dynamic` keyword to accomplish this...

Make your scavenger class like this:

```
public class Scavenger
{
    private readonly dynamic _lookup;

    public Scavenger(dynamic lookup)
    {
        _lookup = lookup;
    }

    public string WhatIs(string key)
    {
        if (_lookup.ContainsKey(key)) return _lookup[key];
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will attempt to find the methods at runtime instead. See more at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [ImpromptuInterface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface). I've used it to essentially do duck typing-like behavior.

C# does allow duck typing, to some degree, thanks to the dynamic language runtime introduced in 4.0 (I believe it was 4.0), just be very careful you don't burn yourself. ImpromptuInterface is proof of this.

Comment: `C# does allow duck typing` no it doesn't.

Comment: @Servy I think it's arguable that dynamic fits as duck typing, and even if you don't agree, then this `ImpromptuInterface` certainly strikes me as duck typing. Your assertion that `c# doesn't allow duck typing` is too broad to be helpful.

Comment: `ImpromptuInterface` is a somewhat closer attempt at mimicking that feature, however having it properly implemented in the language would result in programs that don't compile if an object does not meet the given contract.  While `ImpromptuInterface` limits the places in which static typing is removed, and makes the code more readable and self-documenting than `dynamic` (by a wide margin) it still happily allows programs to compile that will fail at runtime.

Comment: I agree that c#'s implementation is suboptimal especially compared to structural typing, but that doesn't mean "c# does not allow duck typing".

Comment: @Servy: I'd argue it allows it by proxy; dynamic objects (declared with dynamic instead of var), combined with using ExpandoObject and ImpromptuInterface is the closest you can get to duck typing with C#. Yes it allows compilation, but the risk of runtime exceptions occurs in almost any language that natively allows duck typing, regardless of what you try and defend against.

It's not native to the language (IronPython, for example), it can be nearly mimicked. Hah, mimicking duck typing...seems kind of silly in a way.

Comment: @AdamSears A proper implementation of duck typing means that programs that compile will not fail because a type doesn't contain the appropriate members.  There is no runtime binding; it is all done at compile time.

Comment: @Servy Can you please name a language that does this? I'm legitimately curious as my limited language exposure is C# and [Iron]Python.

Comment: @AdamSears C++ templates are a great example of this.  I also posted [this link](http://ericlippert.com/2014/01/02/what-is-duck-typing/) in a comment on another answer, which has a few other languages with even stronger versions of this.

Comment: "In a duck-typed language, the equivalent function would take an object of any type and call that object's walk and quack methods. If the object does not have the methods that are called then the function signals a run-time error."

Is this not what C# does with dynamic? I'm picking a statement out of the article, and from what I understand (in reference to an ExpandoObject), this is exactly how it functions. Is there something I'm missing here?